# Powerful and cheap array algorithms

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how the text messages are normally stored in Firebase realtime-Database

[image: Here]

I am not fond of the idea that every time someone joins a group chat, they would need to download the entire e.g 20000 history text messages. Naturally, users wouldn't swipe all the way up to the very first message. However, in firebase realtime database, storing all messages under a given parent node will cause all messages to be downloaded once a user queries it (to join the group chat).

One possible efficiency solution:

Adding a second parent node that stores older text messages. E.g latest 500 text messages are saved under the main messages parent node and the rest of 19500 old text messages are saved on a different parent node. However, the parent node for old text messages will also need to be updated with newer old text messages. We would then need to download all 19500 old text messages as a consequence.

Perhaps the ideal case is to create up to N parent nodes that store packets of 300 text messages each. However, **what consequence would their be with excessively creating parent nodes?**

**What efficiency solutions are recommended with a problem like this?** Is there some technique I am forgetting or unaware of?

Comment: Use the Firebase Pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the list by date desc and limit to the last N messages. Or save the "inverse" date and sort on that. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).